# nuxt require javascript rendering queue

Tags: jquery, nuxt.js, require

I know jquery is not recommended in vue.js, but I am forced to use jquery and bootstrap using require().

```
<template>
  ~~~
</template>

<script>
  ~~~
if (process.browser) {
    try {
        require("./js/jquery.js");
        require('./bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js');
    } catch(e) 
    {}
}
  ~~~
</script>
```

I'm using bootstrap version 4.x therefore jquery should be required.
I tried like a source, but bootstrap.js loaded first
(Error msg: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery)

server-side-rendering and nuxt used

Please show me any references and sorry for my lack of English

I tried changing the source queue, but it was the same result
always './bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js' rendering first, './js/jquery.js' is lasted

Comment: Have you considered using vue-bootstrap? https://bootstrap-vue.org/

Comment: @zoltalar no, I didn't consider for using the original source.

Comment: bootstrap-vue works really well with vue and nuxt